# Schedule a “named” task so that I can reschedule it

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

I use a `Timer` and `TimerTasks` to schedule some tasks to be execuded.  Some of the tasks must be rescheduled.  I need a mechanism to “name” tasks (e.g. by a String ID) so I can reschedule them or remove them and schedule them at a new time.

The project that I’m working on is a Flight Display System.  Every flight when inserted to the DB has a scheduled arrival and departure time.  So I use one timer task to update airport displays when a flight must be shown and another one to hide it.

Everything is fine until there is a change in the flight time.  The user updates the time in the DB but then I need to reschedule the display update times.  This is the point where I need your help.

Comment: Are you limited to the Timer / TimerTask API or could you use Quartz (http://quartz-scheduler.org/)?

Comment: Thank you I will check it and I will inform you! Seems promising!

Comment: Sorry too complicated! To use it you have to study a few other projects first.

Comment: Could you show your current code?

Comment: This is easily possible using Quartz Schedular..Dont know whether it suits your requirements

Comment: Sorry the project is quite complicated to post any code.
I tried Quartz but then I should study c3p0, log4j, slf4j even to test some samples so after a few hours I quit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you think about a simple `HashMap<UUID, TimerTask> tasks`. You could find any Task by the given ID, cancel it, or reschedule it later.

**update**

```
public class TimerThingy{
    HashMap<UUID,TimerTask> tasks = new HashMap<UUID,TimerTask>();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    public UUID createAndStartTimer(final Runnable task, Date when){
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
            public void run(){
                task.run();
            }
        }
        timer.schedule(TimerTask timerTask, Date when);
        UUID id = UUID.randomUUID(); 
        tasks.put(id, t);
        return id;
    }

    public void cancelTimer(UUID id){
        tasks.get(id).cancel();
    }

}
```

Well this is some kind of easiest Scheduler with an ID to cancel. I think you may use something else as ID, because you may to find the correct Task to cancel. But thats up to you..

Comment: I'm not familiar with HashMap can you provide a simple example please?

Comment: I would like to get some other ideas that is why I do not close the question!

Comment: @Johntor This is really the most straightforward way to implement what you’re asking for. +1

Answer (score 1):

//You can create a map where you store your tasks, indexed by the id.

```
Map<String,TimerTask> tasks = new HashMap<String,TimerTask>();
```

You uses a function to generate your named tasks:

```
public TimerTask createTask(String name, final Runnable r){
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            r.run();
        }
    }

    //here, you save it to the HashMap 
    tasks.put(name, task);
    return task;
}
```

// update airport displays when a flight must be shown and another to hide it.

Now, to create a task, you create the runnable, like you used to, and creates the name you'd want it to have, for example fligthnumer-show, or flightnumer-hide, and then call that function to create the task.

```
Runnable r= ...  //whatever you does here
String name = "1234-show";
TimerTask task = createTask( name,   r);
```

Now, you can schedule the task,or do whatever you need. besides, your task is saved, so, if you need it again, to cancel it, or to schedule it again, you just need to retrieve it from the hashmap, calling it for its name:

```
 TimerTask task = tasks.get("1234-show");
```

In this example, it is not really useful, but in your real application, if you are, for instance, creating task dinamically, is easy to build a dynamic list of tasks. Say you have to schedule a task to show the info or a new flight, that probably you already did the day before, or probably is a new one. You can check if there is a task already, and if it is, you can use it, otherwise you crete it and save it.

```
//say you have flight number in a var called flightNumber, and you are building a "show" task 
String name= flightNumber+"show";

TimerTask task = tasks.get(name); //if the task is found, you can use it

//instead, f there is not such task, null will be returned,  in that case, you create it.
if (null== task) {
    //do al the required stuff, like get the runnable ready, and create the task
    task = createTask( name,   r);
}

//so here, you can do whatever you need with the task
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer is similar to the previews one.

Comment: yeah, i tried to be more explanatory since you said you werent familiar to maps, and also tried to get closer to your specific case and also describe a little how the flow would be

Comment: I would like to get some other ideas that is why I do not close the question!